# RxJS Promises Chaining

Tags: javascript, promise, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm pretty new to RxJS. So I have a stream that creates the payload for different ajax calls, then I use a flatMap to retrieve the data I need and it works fine. Easy.

```
const streamA = Rx.Observable.from(array);

const streamB = streamA
  .map( val => /* build payload */ )
  .flatMap( payload => Rx.Observable.fromPromise($.ajax(payload))

streamB.subscribe( result => /* got it */)
```

Now I would create an array of payloads for every item, but the problem is that now when I subscribe the stream I get every single request back, but I would have only the initial elements to be returned when completed.

```
const streamC = streamA
  .flatMap( payloads => {
    return Rx.Observable.from(payloads)
      .flatMap( payload => Rx.Observable.fromPromise($.ajax(payload))

streamC.subscribe( result => /* executed for every payload */)
```

I tried with the `groupBy` that returns the proper grouped array and showed me that I can chain Observable, but I still can't figure out how properly subscribe the observers to get the elements fulfilled.

```
const streamWLF = streamA
  .flatMap( payloads => {
    return Rx.Observable.from(payloads)
      .flatMap( payload => Rx.Observable.fromPromise($.ajax(payload))
      .groupBy((obs) => obs.key, (obs) => obs)

streamWLF.subscribe( result => {
  result.subscribe(/* did my magic here*/);
})
```

So my question is, which is the best way to do that?

Does the main Stream subscribed always triggered when a subStream item is received?

And, if is possible, how can I subscribe subStream to trigged the mainStream subscribed only when subStream is completed?

Comment: Probably you should use concatMap instead of flatMap.

Comment: I'm not clear on your issue. What do you mean you "would have only the initial elements to be returned when completed"? Promises only return a single item, Are you trying to associate the results of each set of payloads together somehow?

Comment: @paulpdaniels yes, I have items containing an array of payloads, and i want to have back, not all the payloads in a stream, but the elements with the returned payloads inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`forkJoin`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md) operator.

```
const streamC = streamA
  .flatMap(payloads => Rx.Observable.forkJoin(payloads));

streamC.subscribe( results => /*An array containing the results from all payloads*/);
```